# Unknown characters are apped to value of map-node after editing

Tags: yaml-cpp

When I edit an existing yaml file extra string "!" are getting added to value of map-node whose value is string like "'dd'-'MM'". This is happening only during editing but not I create a new YAML file with same data.

e.g:

---

```
Test:
- Key1: "'dd'-'MM'"
- Key2: ABC
...
```

If I edit the above file programatically the result is

---

```
Test:
- Key1: !<!> "'dd'-'MM'"
- Key2: ABC
...
```

I have verified my value string which I am setting, it definitely without "!" string characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the library. Please see the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=202) on the project page.